# Executing code in bash only if a string is not found in a file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to execute a block of code only if the string `SVN_BRANCH` is not found in `/etc/profile`. My current code looks like the following:

```
a = cat /etc/profile
    b = `$a | grep 'SVN_BRANCH'`

    not_if "$b"
{
....
... 
...
}
```

This fails as given. How should it be done?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: Also, see the rules in the Help Center. When asking a question about code that misbehaves, you should always include the specific error or misbehavior (no matter how obvious you might expect it to be to someone reading your code), and include only the bare minimum code needed for that error or misbehavior to occur. In this case, reading the BashGuide (and thus getting a basic understanding of the language) is the better place to start.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` can take file as an argument, you don't need to `cat` the file and then pass the content to `grep` with pipe, that's totally unnecessary.

This is an example of `if else` block with `grep`:

```
if grep -q "pattern" filepath;then
echo "do something"
else
echo "do something else"
fi
```

Note:

`-q` option is for quite operation. It will hide the output of `grep` command (error will be printed).

If you want it to not print any errors too then use this:

```
if grep -sq "pattern" filepath;then
```

Or this:

```
if grep "pattern" filepath >/dev/null 2>&1;then
```

`>/dev/null` is to redirect the output to `/dev/null`

[`2>&1` redirects both stderr and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21)

Comment: `grep -q pattern path` is more efficient than `grep pattern path >/dev/null`, as it allows grep to stop as soon as it finds a match, rather than needing to proceed through the rest of the file generating output that gets thrown away.

Comment: I'd also suggest using `>/dev/null 2>&1` only if that's very explicitly desired -- throwing away errors rather than presenting them to the user hides the causation behind unexpected failures.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the exit code of the grep command to determine whether to execute your code block like this

```
cat /etc/profile | grep SVN_BRANCH 2>&1 >/dev/null || {
....
....
}
```

Comment: Noooo!!! `cat file | grep` is UUoC: use `grep ... file`. Also, this is quite too much, you can just use `grep -q` for the same purpuse.